# Why are changes to Angular template in node_modules not being reflected

Tags: angular, node-modules

I am trying to update html in my node_modules folder and when I change it doesn't get updated. Is it not possible to update files within node_modules?

I have a project that imports a popup module

```
 import {PopupModule} from 'ng2-opd-popup';
```

I need to be able to change the code what exists in this folder path ( /node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/components/popup/**popup.component.html**)

```
div id="ng2-opd-popup-main"  *ngIf="visible" [ngClass]="mainClass" [ngStyle]="mainStyle">
<div class="row">
    <div style="display: inline-block;width:100%">
       <div id="ng2-opd-popup-well"  [ngStyle]="wellStyle" class="ng2-opd-popup-well ng2-opd-popup-well-sm">{{popupService.options.header}}</div>
    </div>
<div style="margin:20px;">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div *ngIf="popupService.options.showButtons" style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;float: right">           
        <div *ngIf="popupService.options.showConfirm">
        <button  id="confirmBtn" [ngClass]="confirmBtnStyle"  (click)="confirmYes()">{{popupService.options.confirmBtnContent}}</button>
        </div>
     <div *ngIf="popupService.options.showCancel">
        <button id="cancelBtn" [ngClass]="cancelBtnStyle" type="reset" (click)="confirmNo()">{{popupService.options.cancelBtnContent}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lets say I want to take out the cancelbutton completely. When I change it and save it from within my project it doesn't update even though the html is changed.

Comment: Ok I am seriously at a loss here. The package that I am trying to change is ng2-opd-popup located here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-opd-popup   I can go into the node_modules > components > popup folder and modify the html but changes are not updated. The git location just shows a sample project and not the actualy nodes module. This can only be installed and seen via NPM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ok I am seriously at a loss here. The package that I am trying to change is `ng2-opd-popup` located here. I can go into the `node_modules > components > popup` folder and modify the html but changes are not updated. The git location just shows a sample project and not the actually nodes module. This can only be installed and seen via NPM.

**Do not change anything in `node_modules`**. It's not your code. It's library code. It's third-party code. It's subject to being replaced/updated every time someone runs `npm install`, or clones your repo anew, or when the repo version updates. You have no way to even know if a particular file is used at run-time; the HTML file for a component's template probably is not. The package is a black box. Depending on how the library is packaged, the template may well have been pre-compiled in a build step run before the package was published.

In this case, for example, TS has been pre-compiled into JS, so any changes you make to TS files would have no effect whatsoever. When you say `import {PopupComponent} from 'ng2-opd-popup';`, you are actually importing a JS file. The HTML has been pre-compiled and in-lined into `popup.component.js`--this is a typical approach used when building libraries for use with Angular. Therefore, any changes you make to `popup.component.html` are completely ignored.

It would have been nice if the developer had had the foresight to add the feature you want--to hide the cancel button--but hey, such is life.

Since there is no such feature, then to eliminate the button, you could hide it with CSS. It might be best to do this globally in `src/styles.css` or `src/styles.scss`, at least for testing purposes: in the `.css` file for the component where you are using this, or in global scope:

```
#cancelBtn { display: none; }
```

If you really wanted more extensive customizations to the component, in ways that were not possible with either available options, or CSS, or possibly JS in some cases, then request them to the developer. Perhaps if they are things other users might want, they will accommodate you. Otherwise, you may end up, as a last resort, doing what is called "forking" the repository. That means making your own copy of the entire repo, which you can edit as you will, built it in the same way the original repo is built, typically with a command such as `npm run build`, and keep it in sync with any future changes to the original pretty easily.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. That show cancel is what I added to the html file. The developer didn't think of that that option. This is one of the many things I wanted to add to this module was the ability to make it more dynamic. I tried the ng-deep css class but for some reason it is not working. I am using angular 4.3.6,  Lastly I do not mind taking what was done in this project and starting my own however I don't have a clue how to do that or get that started. I have all of the component, module and html files for this project

Comment: Try putting the rule in `src/styles.[s]css`,

Comment: "Do not change anything in node_modules" Sometimes u have to. Fix a bug while waiting on you PR to come trough for example. https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package helps with this. Don't be opinionated in your answer, there are plenty of use cases where you can't wait for an author to fix something in a library and you just need a quick fix.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what exactly the problem you're seeing is, changes you make should be visible.  Or are you using something like webpack and it isn't automatically refreshing after you change it?  Because the change detection typically doesn't look at node_modules, so it won't pick that up until you restart the server.

Regardless, you **shouldn't** change anything in node_modules - packages aren't meant to be modified directly.  You should either try to work within the capabilities the package gives you, find a different one that does what you need, or if you're feeling ambitious fork it and modify the original code.  In this case, it looks like you can use the first option - it has a `showCancel` option, so look at the documentation for how to set that.

Comment: Ok I will have to fork it. It works well for what I need but I need just a bit more dynamic behavior from it.

Comment: I will literally pay to get this thing modified at this point

Comment: This. I had to restart my development server to reflect changes I made to debug in one of my node_modules. Thanks.